# Secret role of comment section in CLIPS

Tags: coding-style, comments, clips

Almost every CLIPS construct has an optional *comment* section which can hold some string-like text. I am wondering if this can actually be somehow used.

```
(defrule already-very-informative-rule-name "
   Hi,
   I wrote this rule late saturday evening having some beer and relaxed.
   So the story starts ...
   ...
   "
   (pattern)
   =>
   (action)
)
```

Is there a way to extract a list of methods/rules with their comments? Maybe like automatically generated documentation in Python?

Or are these positional comments just for some unique fancy style of writing inline comments in CLIPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of CLIPS was originally designed to be compatible with the Automated Reasoning Tool (ART). ART supported a comment field, so we supported the same syntax in CLIPS. Personally, in the last thirty years, I've never found much use for it. The comment is included as part of the "pretty print" representation of rules (and other constructs), so from the command line you could use a ppdefrule command to see the rule and its comment, but any comments interspersed throughout the rule using the semicolon comment delimiter would not be displayed. You'd have to look at the rule source file for those. So the only use I can see for it is a brief comment that's applicable to the entire rule such as a version number.